# jQuery AJAX Post Error in Head Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a file (lam.php) that displays a database-driven list of countries in Latin America. I would like to include it in various pages on my website as a convenient reference. But rather than simply include it, I'd like to use AJAX, so the users can decide whether or not they want to view the list.

So I'm learning how to work with AJAX. It sounds like I want to use jQuery + AJAX, using Post instead of Get.

But I immediately got hung up on an error on this line:
    $.post("http://gx/2b/inc/C/Shared/DBLists/World/lam.php",data,callback);

I don't see any errors displayed when I preview the page, but the error is highlighted in Dreamweaver. Nothing happens when I click the button, so there's obviously an error somewhere. Can anyone spot the error(s) in my script?

This is the entire script:

```
<head>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#lam").click(function()
    $.post("http://gx/2b/inc/C/Shared/DBLists/World/lam.php",data,callback);
    )
   }
  )
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="lam">Latin America<button>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you defined the `callback` function?

Comment: You're using the undefined variable `data`.

Comment: I got this from a tutorial. I basically copied their script. How do I define "data" and "callback"? All the data is in the file lam.php, so can I simply delete "data"? "Callback" determines how the data is fetched, right? In other words, I can specify "Display this table when someone clicks the button with the id 'africa'."

Comment: `data` contains the parameters that you want to send to the AJAX server, and `callback` is the function that does something with the response, like display it in a DIV.

Comment: I think you didn't read the whole tutorial, it should show how you define these things.

Comment: The problem is, there are too many tutorials, tutorials focusing on plain AJAX, AJAX with jQuery, AJAX with JSON and on and on. The tutorials aren't on the same page. Some assume a working knowledge of AJAX and don't explain the basics, etc. So far, you've confirmed that my script has problems. I'd like to hear from someone who can show me a working example that DOES work. The file lam.php is nothing more than a table with a list of countries. How should I change my script so it displays that table?

Comment: It seems like you're getting ahead of yourself, you don't seem to understand basic Javascript programming concepts.

Comment: You didn't copy their script, because if you did, it would have included the definition of the callback function, and then you could have modified that function to do what you want.

Comment: (Deleted; I just saw the new answer.)

Comment: I'm not a programmer; I'm a writer who needs to learn enough programming to make my websites work. I asked a very simple, common sense question and really don't appreciate your insults. I would prefer that you don't reply to any of my questions in the future.

Comment: I've learned from a combination of hard work, tutorials and forums. Along the way I've run into a few arrogant geeks who call me and others like me "help vampires." We prefer to steer clear of such people and seek out people who are interested in helping newbies without insulting them. If you don't like my questions, you're free to ignore them. As I suggested, I would prefer that you do exactly that. There are plenty of authentic guru teachers on this forum and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a DIV to the HTML for the result to be displayed in. Then the callback function has to fill in the DIV with the response from the AJAX call.

Since your PHP script doesn't take any parameters, you don't need the `data` argument.

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#lam").click(function()
        $.post("http://gx/2b/inc/C/Shared/DBLists/World/lam.php", function(response) {
            $("#lam-result").html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="lam">Latin America<button>
  <div id="lam-result"></div>
</body>
```